# VBA fails when setting range in Excel

Tags: function, vba, excel, range

Using an example from [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb978779%28v=office.12%29.aspx#DevGuideExcel2007RangeObject_InsertingValuesintoaRange) I'm trying to set the value of a cell in Excel 2007. Here are the steps I took:

1. In the Excel options choose `Enable all Macro's` and `Trust access to VBA object model`.
2. Create a new Excel WorkBook.
3. Add a new VBA Module.
4. Insert the following function:

   ```
   Function MyTest(rg As Range)
       rg.Value = 1
       MyTest = 1234
   End Function
   ```
5. Add the formula `=MyTest(B1)` to the cell at A1.

When the first line of MyTest is executed, the debugger simple fails. Without any error it stops debugging and displays `#VALUE!` in A1. B1 remains empty.

I've tried setting `.Formula` instead of `.Value`. I've tried using `ActiveSheet` and `Worksheets["Sheet1"]` to access Worksheets. What can possibly be the cause of this error?

Comment: Why do you try to set the value on `rg`? What happens when you comment out that line?

Comment: When I comment out `rg.Formula = 1`, A1 changes to 1234 as expected. I try to set rg because I want to change cells programmatically.

Comment: I would not be surprised if the range was read-only. You cannot set more than one cell value with a built-in cell function either. Just set a break point on the offending line to see what the error is in the debugger.

Comment: I have set a breakpoint but cannot deduce what the problem is. I suspect you're right in it being read-only, I just cannot see why.

Comment: I don't think you need to do item 1 on your list. In particular "Trust access to VBA object model" can be dangerous.

Comment: I understand the danger, but for now I just want to solve this problem :) OK, partial answer: if you add the code to a Button control it works..

Answer (score 7, accepted):

VBA functions that are called from cell formulae are not allowed to modify cell contents.  This restriction is in place so that Excel can keep track of dependencies.

If you need to modify cell contents then you'll have to invoke your VBA through some other mechanism, e.g. a user form.